# How do I send a object using JavaScript to Spring Controller using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am making simple Spring MVC web application. In my application I want to send a object from front end to Spring controller method. But when I do this I am getting js error

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I tried to find a good answer in internet but still could not find a good one.

My controller method is

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody String addInventory(@RequestBody InventoryAddParam inventoryAddParam) {

    log.info("addInventory");
    ServiceRequest<InventoryAddParam> serviceRequest =  convertAddParamtoServiceRequest(inventoryAddParam);
    validate(inventoryAddParam);
    inventoryService.addInventory(serviceRequest);
    return "Inventory Added Succesfully";
}
```

inventoryAddParam is a Serializable object that contain only String parameters.

My JavaScript function to send object is

```
function sendDataTest() {
$.ajax({
    url : "/GradleSpringMVC/inventory/add",
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(populateTestObject()),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    mimeType : 'application/json'
}).done(function(data) {
    // temGrid.addJSONData(data);
}).fail(function(error) {
    // parseToPageAlerts(error.responseText);
}).always(function() {
    // hideLoading()
});}
```

I am creating the addParam object to send as ajax call. 
It create in function

```
function populateTestObject(){
var addParam = new InventoryAddParam();
addParam.inventoryId = "INV001";
addParam.name = "ECG MACHINE";
addParam.price = "1000";
addParam.hospital = "Colombo";
addParam.userNote = "User Note";
return addParam;}
```

Do I have done any wrong thing here ?

Other details about the error

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/GradleSpringMVC/inventory/add
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

Header

```
Connection:close
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:4939
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 21 Jan 2015 03:55:19 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: Updated with changes and new exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Just changed the version of jackson to `1.9.12`

```
'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.12'
```

Answer (score 2):

You spring method consumes *application/json* and the error message says that what you're sending is not a valid JSON.

Following that line, I believe that your issue is a `$.extend(addParam)`, when set with a [single argument it will extend a jQuery namespace with the object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), and won't return any JSON object to be stringified (and nothing being sent to the server). The possible solution is either removing the *extend* function, or adding another parameter in which case a valid JSON object will be returned, e.g.

```
function sendData() {
var addParam = createAddParam();
$.ajax({
    url : "/GradleSpringMVC/inventory/add",
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(addParam),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    mimeType : 'application/json'
}).done(function(data) {
    // temGrid.addJSONData(data);
}).fail(function(error) {
    // parseToPageAlerts(error.responseText);
}).always(function() {
    // hideLoading()
});}
```